making a list of undefined citations
I'm looking for a way to get a list of the references that are missing in the .bib file. That is, all that produce a 'undefined citation' warning.
The reason is to help checking the completeness of a very large .bib file.
Any reasonable way to do this? (other than parsing the log?)
thanks

Why don't you check the blg?

What do you mean exactly with "checking the completeness"? If you want a yes/no answer (it is complete or not) then you just need to check if there are any undefined citation warnings at all, if not then it is complete. But if instead you want to solve all such warnings then you will need to add the missing references one by one, which is not too difficult by just reading the log yourself. Do you want to include some automation, and if so, what are you thinking about automating?

Thanks for the answers. Yes, I was thinking on some automation. I'm compiling a book, with 30 chapters, and per-chapter bibliography. I was hoping to get a list of all the undefined citations (I saw this in an article proof by elsevier a while back, they provided a list of the citations that were not in the references list, so the authors could check what was missing). This list would help us identify missing entries in the .bib file

you also get a list of what is missing if you run e.g. biber. but isn't it trivial to get the list of undefined citations? can't you just e.g. grep the .log? (don't know what the equivalent is on windows, but surely windows has something similar?)

As no example was provided, I had to invent one. The typeset document is imperfect with BibTeX because I used an example .bib designed for Biblatex1, but that's irrelevant here.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{notinthebib}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{alsonotinthebib}
\cite{cms}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gone/awol}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{missing-in-action}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{on:strike:refs:say:better:pay}
\cite{geer}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}

LaTeX prints the undefined citations to the log and on the console, both when the citation is used and at the end of the run. So most editors will pick these out for you and it is not too hard to grep or just read them yourself.
Nonetheless, further tools exist, including checkcites. checkcites can list the used-but-undefined, unused-but-defined or both the unused and the undefined references in one or more files.
$ checkcites --undefined prawf-2
     _           _       _ _
 ___| |_ ___ ___| |_ ___|_| |_ ___ ___
|  _|   | -_|  _| '_|  _| |  _| -_|_ -|
|___|_|_|___|___|_,_|___|_|_| |___|___|

checkcites.lua -- a reference checker script (v2.7)
Copyright (c) 2012, 2019, Enrico Gregorio, Paulo Cereda
Copyright (c) 2024, Enrico Gregorio, Island of TeX

Great, I found 19 citations in 1 file. I also found 1 bibliography file.
Let me check this file and extract the references. Please wait a moment.

Fantastic, I found 92 references in 1 bibliography file. Please wait a
moment while the report is generated.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Report of undefined references in your TeX document (that is, references
cited in the TeX source file, but not present in the bibliography files)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Undefined references in your TeX document: 5
=> notinthebib
=> alsonotinthebib
=> gone/awol
=> missing-in-action
=> on:strike:refs:say:better:pay

Those are the 5 citations used in the document but missing from the .bib because I made them up.
$ checkcites --unused prawf-2
     _           _       _ _
 ___| |_ ___ ___| |_ ___|_| |_ ___ ___
|  _|   | -_|  _| '_|  _| |  _| -_|_ -|
|___|_|_|___|___|_,_|___|_|_| |___|___|

checkcites.lua -- a reference checker script (v2.7)
Copyright (c) 2012, 2019, Enrico Gregorio, Paulo Cereda
Copyright (c) 2024, Enrico Gregorio, Island of TeX

Great, I found 19 citations in 1 file. I also found 1 bibliography file.
Let me check this file and extract the references. Please wait a moment.

Fantastic, I found 92 references in 1 bibliography file. Please wait a
moment while the report is generated.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Report of unused references in your TeX document (that is, references
present in bibliography files, but not cited in the TeX source file)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Unused references in your TeX document: 78
=> set
=> stdmodel
=> angenendt
=> baez/article
=> bertram
=> doody
=> gillies
=> glashow
=> herrmann
=> kastenholz
=> murray
=> reese
=> sarfraz
=> shore
=> sigfridsson
=> spiegelberg
=> springer
=> weinberg
=> yoon
=> aristotle:physics
=> aristotle:poetics
=> augustine
=> averroes/bland
=> averroes/hannes
=> averroes/hercz
=> cicero
=> coleridge
=> companion
=> cotton
=> gerhardt
=> gonzalez
=> hammond
=> iliad
=> knuth:ct
=> knuth:ct:a
=> knuth:ct:b
=> knuth:ct:c
=> knuth:ct:d
=> knuth:ct:e
=> knuth:ct:related
=> kullback
=> kullback:reprint
=> kullback:related
=> malinowski
=> maron
=> massa
=> moore
=> moore:related
=> nietzsche:ksa
=> nietzsche:ksa1
=> nussbaum
=> piccato
=> vangennep
=> vangennep:trans
=> vangennep:related
=> vizedom:related
=> vazques-de-parga
=> wilde
=> worman
=> gaonkar
=> gaonkar:in
=> jaffe
=> westfahl:frontier
=> kant:ku
=> nietzsche:historie
=> brandt
=> hyman
=> pines
=> salam
=> ctan
=> itzhaki
=> markey
=> wassenberg
=> kowalik
=> laufenberg
=> sorace
=> padhye
=> loh

That's all the entries in the .bib I didn't use in the example. If you want both lists, though, you might just as soon do
$ checkcites --all prawf-2
     _           _       _ _
 ___| |_ ___ ___| |_ ___|_| |_ ___ ___
|  _|   | -_|  _| '_|  _| |  _| -_|_ -|
|___|_|_|___|___|_,_|___|_|_| |___|___|

checkcites.lua -- a reference checker script (v2.7)
Copyright (c) 2012, 2019, Enrico Gregorio, Paulo Cereda
Copyright (c) 2024, Enrico Gregorio, Island of TeX

Great, I found 19 citations in 1 file. I also found 1 bibliography file.
Let me check this file and extract the references. Please wait a moment.

Fantastic, I found 92 references in 1 bibliography file. Please wait a
moment while the reports are generated.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Report of unused references in your TeX document (that is, references
present in bibliography files, but not cited in the TeX source file)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Unused references in your TeX document: 78
=> set
=> stdmodel
=> angenendt
=> baez/article
=> bertram
=> doody
=> gillies
=> glashow
=> herrmann
=> kastenholz
=> murray
=> reese
=> sarfraz
=> shore
=> sigfridsson
=> spiegelberg
=> springer
=> weinberg
=> yoon
=> aristotle:physics
=> aristotle:poetics
=> augustine
=> averroes/bland
=> averroes/hannes
=> averroes/hercz
=> cicero
=> coleridge
=> companion
=> cotton
=> gerhardt
=> gonzalez
=> hammond
=> iliad
=> knuth:ct
=> knuth:ct:a
=> knuth:ct:b
=> knuth:ct:c
=> knuth:ct:d
=> knuth:ct:e
=> knuth:ct:related
=> kullback
=> kullback:reprint
=> kullback:related
=> malinowski
=> maron
=> massa
=> moore
=> moore:related
=> nietzsche:ksa
=> nietzsche:ksa1
=> nussbaum
=> piccato
=> vangennep
=> vangennep:trans
=> vangennep:related
=> vizedom:related
=> vazques-de-parga
=> wilde
=> worman
=> gaonkar
=> gaonkar:in
=> jaffe
=> westfahl:frontier
=> kant:ku
=> nietzsche:historie
=> brandt
=> hyman
=> pines
=> salam
=> ctan
=> itzhaki
=> markey
=> wassenberg
=> kowalik
=> laufenberg
=> sorace
=> padhye
=> loh

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Report of undefined references in your TeX document (that is, references
cited in the TeX source file, but not present in the bibliography files)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Undefined references in your TeX document: 5
=> notinthebib
=> alsonotinthebib
=> gone/awol
=> missing-in-action
=> on:strike:refs:say:better:pay

The tool can also check cross-references, though I have not tried that feature2.
Note that checkcites uses texlua under the hood and recent versions won't work with a standard Lua. Both texlua and checkcites are included in TeX Live. I imagine MikTeX includes checkcites, but you might want to check rather than relying on my imagination3.
It would be nice if Island of TeX tools were a bit less chatty4, but the script is otherwise quite slick, provided you use BibTeX.
1checkcites uses BibTeX by default, but is supposed to also support Biber. However, I cannot currently figure out how to get it to work in this case, so it is fortunate this question specifies bibtex.
2Actually, I only discovered checkcites 10 minutes ago, so the output above is pretty much a complete log of my success with it so far. What is omitted are my attempts to persuade it to work with Biber, which nobody could call a 'success'.
3texlua is just LuaTeX, so any TeX distribution will include that.
4\begin{gripe}Or at least could be easily made so. Is it just me who wants to redirect and pipe output from command-line tools? Or who doesn't want them to tell me about themselves unless I ask? Maybe that's just old-fashioned?\end{gripe}
